# How long should I keep on adding entries in a Binary Tree?

Tags: java, algorithm

Please find the code below for a simple Binary Search Tree check:

```
class Tree {

    int value;
    Tree left;
    Tree  right;

    public Tree (int a){

        value = a;
        left = right = null;
        }

}



public class VerifyBST {



public static boolean ifBST(Tree myTree, int small , int large){

        if(myTree == null)
            return true;
        if(myTree.value > small && myTree.value < large){

        boolean leftBST = ifBST(myTree.left, small,myTree.value);
        boolean rightBST = ifBST(myTree.right,myTree.value,large);

        return leftBST&&rightBST;
        }
        else{

        return false;
        }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        /*

                4
               / \
              2   6      
             / \  /\
            1   3 5 7         */

        Tree myTree = new Tree(4);

        myTree.left = new Tree(2);
        myTree.right = new Tree(6);

        myTree.left.left = new Tree(1);
        myTree.left.right = new Tree(3);

        myTree.right.left = new Tree(5);
        myTree.right.right = new Tree(7);



        System.out.println("BST or NOT?" + ifBST(myTree,Integer.MIN_VALUE,Integer.MAX_VALUE));




    }

}
```

My Questions:

1. As clear from the code, I have manually entered all the entries of my binary tree, so if there is a case where I need to check for large tree where manual entries won't be a good idea, what should be the best approach one should follow then?
2. Since I have passed `ifBST(myTree,Integer.MIN_VALUE,Integer.MAX_VALUE)` in the main method,does this mean that `Integer.MIN_VALUE = 1` and `Integer.MAX_VALUE = 7` is passed to the method body?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. If you want to create a large tree, I would suggest that you create a `insertIntoTree(Tree node, int value)` function which adds a new node in the proper location. You can then call that function in a loop as many times as you need, probably with randomly generated values. Note though that you risk ending up with an unbalanced BT, but still a BT.
2. No, it will not pass 1 and 7 to `ifBST`, it will pass the minimum and maximum possible values for the Integer type - which probably is -2^31-1 and 2^31.

Answer (score 0):

1) It sounds like you want to write an add function. This is a function that would traverse the tree, starting at the root. If the value you wish to insert is less than the root node, enter the left node. If it is greater than the root node, enter the right node. Use recursion to repeat this until the node you are going to enter is null. Then create a new tree node at that point and set the left or right child to that node.

2) Think about the conditions that make it a binary search tree. The left node should be smaller than the parent, the right larger. Using these conditions how would you ensure the validity of the tree